# Cross check for the derivative of a unit vector $\frac{x}{|x|}$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Can you please help me in finding out the mistakes I am doing during the calculation of derivative of a vector.
I am briefing the problem I am trying to solve as follows.

There is a line joining two points (1) and (3) as shown in the image below. The possible degrees of freedom at each of the points are shown as $d_{1,1}$, $d_{1,2}$ of point (1) in x- and y- directions. It is similar for point (3) as well.

[image]

The vector at the original configuration is calculated as,

$V_{130}$ = $X_{30}$ - $X_{10}$

The new orientation of the vector $v_{13}$ due to these displacement is 
$v_{13} = V_{130}+d_{3}-d_{1}$

And the unit vector $c_{13} = \dfrac{v_{13}}{\det{v_{13}}}$

Now, I am trying to calculate the derivative of the unit vector as follows

$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}}}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}$ = $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}$
$(\frac{v_{13} }{\det{v_{13} } }) $

where, i is the point number (1 or 3) and n is the component number (1 or 2).

$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}}}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}$ = $\dfrac{
\det{v_{13} \dfrac{\partial{v_{13}}}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}} 
-
v_{13}
\dfrac{v_{13}^{T}}{\det{v_{13}}}
\dfrac{\partial{v_{13}}}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}
}
{\det{v_{13}}^2}$

= $\dfrac{
\left[
I
-
\dfrac{v_{13}}{\det{v_{13}}}
\dfrac{v_{13}^{T}}{\det{v_{13}}}
\right]
}
{\det{v_{13}}^2}
\det{v_{13}}
\dfrac{\partial{v_{13}}}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}
$

= $\dfrac{
\left[
I
-
c_{13}
c_{13}^{T}
\right]
}
{\det{v_{13}}}
\dfrac{\partial{v_{13}}}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}$

= $\dfrac{
\left[
I
-
c_{13}
c_{13}^{T}
\right]
}
{\det{v_{13}}}
(\delta_{3i}-\delta_{1i})
\left[
\begin{array}{1}
\delta_{1n} \\ \delta_{2n}
\end{array}
\right]
$

The above delta is Kronecker delta.

Can you please correct the above outcome of derivative?

**Cross-Checking**:
When I am trying to cross check if the above derivative is correct, I am finding a discrepancy as shown below.

There is a line with coordinates $X_{10} = (-1,-1)$ and $X_{30} = (1,1)$ at its original configuration as shown in the image

[image: Original and rotated line]

The vector at the original configuration is calculated as,

$V_{130}$ = $X_{30}$ - $X_{10}$ = $\left[\begin{array}{l}2\\2\end{array}\right]$

The displacement of the points 1 and 3 are (new coordinate - old coordinate),

$d_1$ = $\left[\begin{array}{l}1\\ -\sqrt(2)+1 \end{array}\right]$
$d_3$ = $\left[\begin{array}{l}-1\\ \sqrt(2)-1 \end{array}\right]$

$v_{13} = V_{130}+d_3-d_1 = \left[\begin{array}{l}0\\ 2\sqrt(2) \end{array}\right]$

And the unit vector $c_{13} = \dfrac{v_{13}}{\det{v_{13}}}$ = $\left[\begin{array}{l}0\\ 1 \end{array}\right]$

Upon substitution in the above derivation formula,

$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}}}{\partial{d_{1,1}}} = 
\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}
\left[
I
-
\left[
\begin{array}{3}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\right]
(-1)
\left[
\begin{array}{1}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

=
$
\dfrac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{1}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$;
$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}}}{\partial{d_{1,2}}} = 0$

$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}}}{\partial{d_{3,1}}} = 
\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{1}
1\\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$; 
$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}}}{\partial{d_{3,2}}} = 0$

Upon rearranging,

$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}^{1}}}{\partial{d_{1,n}}} = \dfrac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}
\left[\begin{array}{1}1\\0 \end{array}\right]$;
$\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}^{1}}}{\partial{d_{3,n}}} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}
\left[\begin{array}{1}1\\0 \end{array}\right]$

By using chain rule of differentiation,
$c^{1}_{13} = \dfrac{\partial{c^{1}_{13}}}{\partial{d_{1,n}}} \ d_{1,n}
+
\dfrac{\partial{c^{1}_{13}}}{\partial{d_{3,n}}} \ d_{3,n}
$

$c_{13}^{1}$ = $ \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}} 
\left[\begin{array}{1}
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
*
\left[\begin{array}{1}
1 \\ -\sqrt(2)+1
\end{array}
\right] 
+ \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} 
\left[\begin{array}{1}
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
*
\left[\begin{array}{1}
-1 \\ \sqrt(2)-1
\end{array}
\right] 
= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$;

$c_{13}^{2}$ =0

(WHICH IS NOT CORRECT).
Can you please help me in which part of the calculation went wrong. Please let me know if you need any clarifications in the whole, I can re-explain to make you understand.

Comment: Incomprehensible. *What* are the supposed variables $d_{i,n}$? Components of the **constant** vectors $d_i$???? The formula $\dfrac{\partial{c_{13}}}{\partial{d_{i,n}}} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{d_{i,n}}}$ has a typo?

Comment: To address the question in the title: the derivative of $f(x)=x/|x|$ at a point $v$ is $D_xf(v)=-v/|x|^2$.

Comment: Thank you @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, I have corrected based on your comments.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHoppe, Can you please comment on the derivation in the description as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure that we are understanding: you want to calculate the derivative of the function $f\colon {\mathbb R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to {\mathbb R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, given by $$f ( x ) = x / |x|.$$
Namely, $f$ takes vectors to unit vectors (vectors of length one). Correct?

Comment: Yes @peter a g, you are right. I am deriving f w. r.t dependencies of f.

Comment: Then I think the easiest way to do this is geometrically: if one goes radially out (i.e., in the same direction as $x$), $f$ is constant. So the derivative vanishes in that direction. If one chooses a path $\theta \mapsto \gamma (\theta)$ through $x$ on the circle of  radius $r = |x|$, $f$ is linear: namely $f\circ\gamma(\theta) = \gamma(\theta)/r$. Hence $f'(x) \gamma'(0) = \gamma'(0)/r$ - i.e., is multiplication by $1/r$ in that direction. This describes the derivative (the linear map) $f'(x)$ in terms of a basis.... OK? (So I disagree with Michael's answer above...)

Comment: My $f'(x)$ is what Michael denoted with $D_xf$... (Notation!)

Comment: Another way of saying this is with polar coordinates: $F(r,\theta) = (1,\theta)$. Is that helpful?

Comment: Thank you @peter a g, for your explanation in polar coordinates. Can you also please also comment on the problem given the description? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write $P$ for the point $(x,y)$, and $T$ for the derivative $f'(P) = D_Pf$.  Then (matrix multiplication)
$$ T  \pmatrix{x&-y\\y&x}= {1\over r}\pmatrix{0&-y\\0&x},$$
where $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This follows from my [first] description of the derivative.
Therefore $$ T = {1\over r^3}\pmatrix{y^2&-yx\\-xy&x^2}.$$
I am putting all of this as a comment (rather than as an answer below), because on the one hand, I don't think it's what you want, and on the other, I don't understand what you want... Sorry!

Comment: I just imagining a reduced situation of this problem. I the link below, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177310/how-to-cross-check-the-derivative-of-a-vector. Can you please look at this if you have any comments, I would be so grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If y = m*x+c is derived by x, which results in m.
The derivative, (dy/dx)*x is not equal to y.

Thus lets understanding that this this question is not feasible to get solved.